# Does List and dictionary in python have a limited capacity ? if yes,how much is it?

Tags: python

Does List and dictionary in python have a limited capacity ? if yes,how much is it ?

Comment: If you do run out of memory there are plenty of ORMs you could use to choose from to simulate a much larger amount of memory

Answer (score 5):

Yes, It is `sys.maxsize`.

```
import sys
print sys.maxsize
```